# Android Application Starts with wrong activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

My Application has 3 activities (MainActivity,SampleActivity,TempActivity) and Application have to start from MainActivity because i register it in AndroidManifest as

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TempActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SampleActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
     </activity>
```

when i switch from MainActivity to TempActivity and come back to MainActivity and then close the Application then often it starts from TempActivity. 
 after this wrong behavior when ever i start my application it starts from Wrong Activity(TempActivity). 
 Please help me in this problem

Comment: how you are closing your application?

Comment: by taping on Home Button

Comment: That is the issue friend.When you are tapping home button application is not closed but keep running in background.that's why it is resuming from where you pressed home button.

Comment: even after restarting my device i am facing same problem...

Comment: when i reinstall the app and then it runs fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when u go from TempActivity activity to MainActivity u give finish()
example:
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(TempActivity.this, MainActivity .class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
      finish();

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse your activity is not destroyed, it is only paused (Check the Activity [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)). You can override `onPause` to perform the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

How are you closing the app, means by home button application dont destroy activities, activity is stopped only. To exit your application you need to finish all of your activities in application.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you press home button you are assuming your application is closed.But it is not!!!

As per android activity life cycle you application will keep running in background and when you press application icon it will start from where it went to background.

If you are on  TempActivity and if you press home button then it will start from TempActivity only.To make sure when you press home button your activity should start with MainActivity
do following changes in your code.

**TempActivity.java**

```
@Override
void onPause()
    {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    }
```

So when next time you will open your application it will start with MainActivity.

Comment: thanks <br> i finish the TempActivity immediate after firing intent of MainActivity and it works... <br> but if this problem again occur then i will also finish TempActivity in onPause()